# How do I use CR?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-gm

I am trying to plan my first encounter in a *Pathfinder* Campaign and I am at a loss for how to use the CR system. On the [one hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering#Table-Experience-Point-Awards), the example given details that someone could bolster thier CR8 boss with up to four CR4 flunkies. On the other hand, not two paragraphs later, they talk about increasing CR based on the number of [identical creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering#Table-CR-Equivalencies) used. So, since there is a HUGE difference between 3 Goul Hounds and 3 Kobold snipers, how am I supposed to use the CR system? Am I supposed to use the whole experience pool that they give me, so long as their individual CR doesn't exceed the Max, or is the Max CR supposed to be the **sum** of the other CRs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a whole system of adding CR with how you calculate it and whatnot, which is not just summing up the numbers, but it is important to note that **it is really dumb**.

In reality, the vast majority of competent GMs use CR as at-best a rough guide to relative monster power.  Parties vary in strength, both in mechanics and in tactics, and will be stronger vs some encounters than others - additionally, elements like terrain, timing, ambush, how many spells the party has left, if the party has all their gear, etc, will vastly change the difficulty level of fights you throw at the party - additionally, sometimes you'll want to toss an easy fight at the party, to show that these low level Gianelli family mooks are no big deal, or a hard fight to show the Brotherhood of the Eightfold Dragon is nothing to mess with.

Basically, **eyeballing encounter strength** is a major GM skill.

The only way I can suggest to make it easier is to think about fights before you have them.  Fights are relatively modular - the party can fight the Gianelli goons in the bordello, or when they come to roust the PCs out of the inn they're staying at, or even at the Gianelli hideout in the old nightclub near the docks.  Wherever the fight happens, the capablities of the Gianelli enforcers will be the same - you can consider the fight, how much hp they have vs how much damage the party generally does, how much damage the enforcers do vs how much AC and HP the party has, whether the enforcers will know to avoid clustering for area spells and if they have good saving throws, etc, and get a rough idea of how the fight will go, before the party even does that fight.

Think each fight through before it happens.  If it might happen in a way that will hurt the party, such as say in a room next to a bunch of reinforcements, or on a rope bridge over a lava river, consider that as well - remember, your job is largely avoiding auto-TPKs - if they party does something clever and makes the fight easier, that kind of creative thinking is not something you're seeking to avoid, but rather to enable.

Comment: So, just pay attention to the XP I throw at them and their individual/net competence and skills. Got it

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a terrible answer, but I just use it as a rough estimate.  Understand that someone, somewhere thought that a CR 5 monster is probably stronger than a CR 3 monster, and leave it at that.  Getting experience running the game, and more importantly, learning your players and their characters, will help you more than any breakdown of how combining CRs is *supposed* to work or what percentage of a party's resources are supposed to be spent on an encounter of CR *x*.

The list of exceptions to how CR works is, at minimum, a decent essay, if not a short book.  Practice and a healthy amount of skepticism are pretty much the only tools that will really help you apply the CR system to your game.

Comment: I originally wrote a lot more than this, with some actual mechanics in there, but I realized it really, really didn't help.  Sorry I'm not more help, but this is probably the most honest answer you can get.